# Time stretching a movie clip not working in render

Tags: rendering, timeline

I have a movie clip in my scene as images on planes. My video is at 60 fps. As this will render twice as many frames, I would like to decrease the frame rate to 30. I have managed to do this in the viewport by changing the frame rate to 30 and time stretching the clip to be twice as fast, thus canceling out the slow down in the change of frame rate. this works exactly how I wanted in the viewport. With the video using half as many frames.

The problem is that it doesn't work in the render. The render keeps time stretching on elements that actually move in the scene but doesn't apply to the movie clip like it does in the viewport.

Is this a glitch in rendering or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I solved my problem by importing the video with a different frame rate but I'm going to keep this up because the problem in blender isn't solved